# error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals

Tags: unresolved-external

Helo, this is my first post here.

I have searched the forum first and few of them were a bit related to my linkage error but still I couldn't remove the error that I am getting. Following are the errors and 6 more errors exactly like the Error 2.

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   _*imp*_hismodgametrak_resetLevel referenced in function "private: void __thiscall DemoApp::startClient(char const *,int)" (?startClient@DemoApp@@AAEXPBDH@Z)  D:\New SVN FOR
>   CAVE\Tools\GameEngine\Samples\TutorialApp\DemoApp.obj DemoApp
>
> Error 8   error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals   D:\New SVN FOR
>   CAVE\Tools\GameEngine\bin\DemoAppd.exe   DemoApp

Does some one has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem in [this forum](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/286471-6-unresolved-externals/page__p__1669051__fromsearch__1&#entry1669051).

Anyone can follow and use it for his/her purpose too for solving thier problem. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "irprops.lib")
```

Using the Winsock Stacks. So my Includes look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <initguid.h>
// Link to ws2_32.lib
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2bth.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "irprops.lib")
```

An excellent answer here: [Fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361308/fatal-error-lnk1120-4-unresolved-externals) helped me out!!! Thanks Victor!!!