# Fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am new to game developing, i am interesed in Goldsrc(Valve's early engine).
I found source code of Counter-Strike 1.6 (Modified Goldsrc) and tried to compile it with VS2013.

Few errors came up - http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/809/qdfh.png
Modied Goldsrc - http://www.mediafire.com/download/798fcj9tb771r6z/CSSDK-master.rar

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Generally, this error comes when you call something that is not defined. (E.g You call a function that has no body in the file you are `#include`-ing in your source code)

> *An undefined external symbol (symbol) was found in function. To resolve this error, provide a definition for symbol or remove the code that references it*

As it is said on Microsoft's website. You can find ways to solve this error following their tips.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z.aspx

The symbols definitions are located in the `.lib` file provided bu Visual Studio when you compile a DLL. Basically, you have to include that `.lib`. file in your executable file.

Right click on your project in the Solution manager dialog and click `Properties`. You have to go to the `Common Properties`, then click `Add New Reference`.

[image]

Comment: I know it's a duplicate question, but there's not enough credit here for a good answer :)

Comment: You gave a good clear and concise answer that addressed the question without belittling the OP - I just thought you deserved more than one upvote